# BASH: How to remove all files except those named in a manifest?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, find

I have a manifest file which is just a list of newline separated filenames. How can I remove all files that are *not* named in the manifest from a folder?

I've tried to build a `find ./ ! -name "filename"` command dynamically:

```
command="find ./ ! -name \"MANIFEST\" "
for line in `cat MANIFEST`; do
    command=${command}"! -name \"${line}\" " 
done
command=${command} -exec echo {} \;
$command
```

But the files remain.

[Note:] I know this uses echo. I want to check what my command does before using it.

**Solution:**(thanks [PixelBeat](http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html#sets))

```
ls -1 > ALLFILES
sort MANIFEST MANIFEST ALLFILES | uniq -u | xargs rm
```

**Without temp file:**

```
ls -1 | sort MANIFEST MANIFEST - | uniq -u | xargs rm
```

Both Ignores whether the files are sorted/not.

Comment: Thanks All! I'm giving it to pixelbeat for his shell guide that held the solution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the "set difference" pattern from http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html#sets

```
(find ./ -type f -printf "%P\n"; cat MANIFEST MANIFEST; echo MANIFEST) |
  sort | uniq -u | xargs -r rm
```

Note I list MANIFEST twice in case there are files listed there that are not actually present.
Also note the above supports files in subdirectories

Comment: I get `rm: missing operand` on your command. I just figured it out using ls, comm, and xargs. Thanks anyway pb

Comment: Add a -r to xargs to remove that warning (when no files are needed to be deleted)

Comment: Set difference pattern using `grep` instead:

    `find ./ -type f -printf "%P\n" | fgrep -vf MANIFEST |...`

Answer (score 15):

For each *file* in current directory **grep** filename in MANIFEST file and **rm** *file* if not matched.

```
for file in *
  do grep -q -F "$file" PATH_TO_YOUR_MANIFIST ||  rm "$file" 
done
```

Comment: If you use this method, be sure to add the name of your manifest file to the manifest itself in case you're putting it in the same directory as where you're deleting files. If you put this code in a script, also add the name of that script to the manifest.

Answer (score 5):

figured it out:

```
ls -1 > ALLFILES
comm -3 MANIFEST ALLFILES | xargs rm
```

Comment: Yes comm -3 is equivalent to my solution above. But be careful as comm expects already sorted inputs

Comment: Cheers, eneded up using the set difference of unsorted.

Comment: Use `xargs -L 1` if your filenames contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a Perl 1-liner... not really needed in this case but much more customizable/extensible than Bash if you want something fancier :)

```
$ ls
1   2   3   4   5   M
$ cat M
1
3
$ perl -e '{use File::Slurp; %M = map {chomp; $_ => 1} read_file("M"); $M{M}=1; \
foreach $f (glob("*")) {next if $M{$f}; unlink "$f"||die "Can not unlink: $!\n" };}' 
$ ls
1   3   M
```

The above can be even shorter if you pass the manifest on STDIN

```
perl -e '{%M = map {chomp; $_ => 1} <>; $M{M}=1; \
foreach $f (glob("*")) {next if $M{$f};unlink "$f"||die "Can not unlink: $!\n" };}' M
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumes that MANIFEST is already sorted:

```
find -type f -printf %P\\n | sort | comm -3 MANIFEST - | xargs rm
```